# Best way to move a site to a subfolder for testing purposes?

Tags: customization, backup, testing

I have to make several changes to a website, and I'm willing to setup a copy of the current one on a subdirectory, on the same server.

I.E. if my site is `www.example.com`, what I'm trying to do is to fully copy it to `www.example.com/new/`, make all the necessary modifications, then, once it is done, copy it back to the main directory.

I know that it is not a simple matter of moving files, I guess that this is a complex matter involving different file paths and database entries. I'd like to know how can I safely do it and it the whole process has to be done manually or if there are some automatic tools (i.e. plugins) that can help me doing it without mistakes.

Comment: its depend on technology used in your site. if its in wordpress, than you can use plugin or also you can do it manually.

Comment: Setup a localhost where you can development off line, once you done, upload your theme to your live site. There are a lot of info on this subject on-site, so please make use of the site search feature

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have discovered that the easiest way to migrate a site is by using the [Duplicator](https://wordpress.org/plugins/duplicator/) plugin; it manages both files and database.

Answer (score 0):

Try these options for move site into sub folder 
 1.You can create sub domain and then copy all your files into your sub domain directory. for database use DB migrate plugin and set your database.
 
2. Other way is just create folder and copy all files into new folder and , from admin update site url